# How to offer a "per customer" isolated linux environment (low cost/automated/scalable)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, deployment, automation, containers

I'm currently wrapping my head around the question: how can I offer automated and isolated linux environments for customers. Since the amount of customers can vary, it also has to be scalable as well.

The goal is that after a customer purchases a certain product, the system starts building and deploying a customized `linux` environment where only he has access to. This environment is really only customized regarding some texts and images depending on the personal information of the customer, but not software-wise. Software depends on the product, could be a webserver running or mysql database or both, the software would be the same for everyone buying that specific product.

**My questions are:**

- Can this be done with kubernetes?
- Are there alternative solutions?